# what would be the scientific name of this variety of dove

Tags: nomenclature

recently i came across a small dove who had its feathers tied by a rubber band so that it $would'nt$ fly. it looks some what like this

[image]

i was stunned by seeing it as i have never seen a dove in brown colour. and after staring it for some time i noticed that it's feathers or hairs near the neck region were made into a cluster that makes it look like $spike$ $hair$ $style$

so in short what would be the scientific name of this dove ??

Comment: This look like a Indian Pigeon(Rock Dove).

Comment: @DevashishDas i know you live in bangalore so have you seen these birds around your locality as these birds are'nt seen very often in hyderabad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a rock pigeons (Columba livia).

[image]

### The Color coding of Pigeon

There are three genes responsible for pigmentation in pigeons.

> – *Tyrp1* gene produces a protein that helps make the pigment eumelanin.
>   Pigeons with blue-black feathers have normal *Tyrp1*. Ash-red and brown
>   birds pigeons contain different mutations in the *Tyrp1* gene, which
>   leads to less or different pigmentation.
>
> – Mutations that affect the *Sox10* gene override colors determined by
>   various versions of the *Tyrp1* gene. Regardless of whether the *Tyrp1*
>   version makes pigeons blue-black, ash-red or brown, mutations that
>   regulate the *Sox10* gene result in red pigeons.
>
> – Mutation of the *Slc45a2* gene decreases the intensity of colors
>   determined by *Tyrp1*, *Sox10* and their mutants. Depending on the version
>   of the Tyrp1 gene – blue-black, ash-red, and brown − pigeons harboring
>   the mutant Slc45a2 gene still display the same colors, but in
>   watered-down or diluted versions, less intense than those with normal
>   *Slc45a2*. For example, a pigeon with both the ash-red version of *Tyrp1*
>   and the mutant *Slc45a2* gene has ash-yellow feathers. Pigeons with
>   *Sox10* and *Slc45a2* mutations are yellow, which is the dilute form of
>   **red.**

Source: http://unews.utah.edu/news_releases/birds-of-a-different-color/

Source: University of Utah

Comment: but what about the arrangement of birds hairs on its neck ???

Comment: @agharehanabbas: I pretty sure this a pigeon because of the beak. PS: can you post the picture of the neck if you are in doubt?

Comment: surely i will edit my question with that pic